# Java nio: How to read characters from memory mapped file with correct charset

Tags: java, character-encoding, nio, memory-mapped-files

for a new project, I have to read the characters of a file (with configurable encoding) to handle the input. As some of these files can be quite large (> 100MB), I wanted to check out the Java nio's ability to memory map files for faster access.

However, I was not able to figure out, how I am able to create something "Reader"-like to read from the MappedByteBuffer with the correct charset decoding.

To create the MappedByteBuffer, I currently use:

```
    RandomAccessFile raFile = new RandomAccessFile("myFile.bla", "r");
    FileChannel channel = raFile.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer = channel.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
```

I know, that I can use getChar() to get a character from the MappedByteBuffer, but how is it possible to specify the encoding? In the javadoc it states, that always two bytes are read and combined to one char, but what is with ASCII encoded files?

I also found the Channels.newReader(...) methods, which however can only handle the channel, not the memory mapped file. Is there something similar for the MappedByteBuffer?

Just to make sure: I know that memory mapping is a somewhat expensive operation and therefore only useful for larger files. I made no decision (yet), whether to use it or not, but want to evaluate it for my special use case.

Many thanks in advance + best regards,
Andreas

Comment: Why don't you get the underlying bytes and construct a `String` with the appropriate `Charset`?

Comment: Memory mapping is not expensive for small files either. It takes around 30 micro-seconds which is not so slow.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Building a String is not efficient, as I need the single characters and analyze the context depending on them. After this, some of the characters may be combined to a string. (Something similar to lexing a source code file).

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) retrieved from your favorite [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) with [`Charset#newDecoder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#newDecoder--).

```
StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder().decode(mappedByteBuffer)
```

This returns a [`CharBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) from which you can [get `char` values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#get--).

Note that this does consume the full `MappedByteBuffer`. If you only want a few bytes, construct a new `ByteBuffer` from the few bytes of the original `MappedByteBuffer` and decode that.

Comment: +1 You can take a slice() to select some bytes from a larger ByteBuffer.

Comment: I actually want to consume all the data, however, I need to do it character by character. Decoding all at once is no option, as it requires double the memory, whereas decoding on the fly requires no extra space. I am actually looking for a way to decode the memory mapped file on the fly like a Reader does with a FileInputStream.

Comment: @andy The memory mapped file is already in Java memory. Take bytes from it as you wish.

Comment: I know that, the thing is: I want to read characters decoded in a specific charset (which might be different from file to file). For this reason I hoped to find something similar to a Reader handling all the decoding for me but working on the memory mapped file.

Comment: @andy There's no `Reader` or `InputStream` type that reads from a `ByteBuffer`. You can implement your own. As discussed in my answer (and Peter's comment), take 2 bytes at a time, wrap them in a `ByteBuffer`, and decode it to a `CharBuffer` from which you can get the `char`.