# MemoryMapped File reading from a huge file separated by new line character

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files

I am reading a huge file using memory mapped I/O.
The problem which i came across is, i am reading MemoryMappedByteBuffer character by character the . So i need to pass multiple strings present in the file which are separated by "\n".

```
        RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(this.getFileName(), "r");
        FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer buffer = inChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 
        0, inChannel.size());

        buffer.load(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++)
        {   // There are many strings in the file separated by \n
            System.out.println((char) buffer.get() == '\n'); // Gives true 
             //need to make a complete string over here.
        }
        buffer.clear(); // do something with the data and clear/compact it.           
        return null; // The String which has been made in the above for loop
```

Comment: Is your problem that you want to build a list of strings, and your question is 'how to do it'?

Comment: Also, if you're just iterating over each character in the file sequentially, why read this "huge file" in all at once?  This problem would be much simpler (and less memory intensive) if you read it in using a `BufferedReader`.

Comment: What exactly *is* the question here?

Comment: @EJP: I need to improve the time required to read a particular file.

Comment: @GregKopff: It will be much simpler about what you are saying and i have implemented by using the same approach but i need to improve the time required for file reading which can be reduced by 8/10 seconds by using memory mapped i/o.

Comment: Then this should be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740370/java-nio-how-to-read-characters-from-memory-mapped-file-with-correct-charset?rq=1

Comment: @VinayakPingale Make up your mind. *Either* you 'need to improve the time' *or* 'the time required for file reading ... can be reduced by 8/10 seconds by using memory mapped I/O'. If the latter is true the former is false, and *vice versa.* I *strongly* suggest you use a `BufferedReader`. You can read millions of lines per second with that, and no memory problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer you're asking for, as this does not use a memory-mapped file.  If it's truly not helpful, I'll remove it.

> I am reading a huge file using memory mapped I/O

If the file really is huge, then the approach you're taking is going to be quite memory demanding.

An alternative is to use a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--), and this makes your task quite trivial:

```
final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charset));

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
  lines.add(line);
}

return lines;
```

An equivalent of this code is already included in the JDK utility method [`Files.readAllLines(Path,Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-):

> Read all lines from a file. This method ensures that the file is
>     closed when all bytes have been read or an I/O error, or other runtime
>     exception, is thrown. Bytes from the file are decoded into characters
>     using the specified charset.
>
> ```
> public static List<String> readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs) throws IOException
> ```

Comment: I have used the same approach, but the time required to read the file needs to be improved by a significant amount which can be achieved by using memory mapped i/o.